# Post scores to myarcadeplugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post

Before I start I should warn you that I'm very newbie, and my php knowledge is little. So I´m sorry if you find a very simple problem because of my lack of knowledge.

**The problem:**

I developed a game in html5 that I add to my wordpress site, the game should send the scores to myarcadeplugin but it´s not working...

**The plugin developer gave me this instructions:**

- The game should submit following details to the score handling file:

  - WordPress Post ID
  - Current User ID
  - Score
  - Score sort order (DESC or ASC)
- In the score handling file you should process the submitted data.

  - $session is a random session number. You can generate it randomly.
  - $game_tag can be retrieved with the submitted post ID: 
    $game_tag = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mabp_game_tag', true );
  - $user_id is submitted by the game
  - $score is submitted by the game
  - $score_order is submitted by the game and it should be DESC or ASC

  `$score_array = array(
    'session'   => $session,
    'date'      => date('Y-m-d'),
    'datatype'  => 'number',
    'game_tag'  => $game_tag,
    'user_id'   => $user_id,
    'score'     => $score,
    'sortorder' => $score_order,
  );`
- Now you can pass scores to MyArcadePlugin

  `if ( function_exists('F007F675CEB78537E7BF8DAFCBBA7AEF0') ) {
   F007F675CEB78537E7BF8DAFCBBA7AEF0( $score_array );
  } elseif ( function_exists('myarcade_handle_score') ) {
  myarcade_handle_score( $score_array );
  }`

In the game I have the variables *wordpress post id* / *current user id* / *score* receiving the correct data, I tried to post this data to my database and it works. So I think the problem is in the php code in the file that post the data to myarcadeplugin, the php code in that file is this:

```
    `<?php
header('Access-Allow-Control-Origin: *');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

$post_id = $_POST['postid'];
$session = $token;
$game_tag = get_post_meta( $post_id,'mabp_game_tag', true );
$user_id = $_POST['userid'];
$score = $_POST['score'];


$score_array = array(
      'session'   => $session,
      'date'      => date('Y-m-d'),
      'datatype'  => 'number',
      'game_tag'  => $game_tag,
      'user_id'   => $user_id,
      'score'     => $score,
      'sortorder' => DESC           /* I dont know how to pass this information so I tried this away and tried to remove it... 
    );


if ( function_exists('F007F675CEB78537E6BF8DBFEOLK3TCC2') ) {
     F007F675CEB78537E6BF8DBFEOLK3TCC2( $score_array );
  } elseif ( function_exists('myarcade_handle_score') ) {
    myarcade_handle_score( $score_array );
  }

?>
```

`

This is not working... I appreciate any help ;)

Comment: Why would you have a function called `F007F675CEB78537E6BF8DBFEOLK3TCC2` ?

Comment: I dont know. It was the plugin developer that gave me that code to pass  the scores to myarcadeplugin... unfortunately already passed two weeks and the plugin developer has not yet replied.